# Google Endpoints: How does the IDE (or terminal) authentify to GAE when uploading code?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new to Google Endpoints and Datastore. I've followed several tutorials, among which this one for example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-codelab-android

My question is: what is the security mechanism that is used when we deploy the Endpoints backend application to Google App Engine? How does Google App Engine know you are the owner of the project? And I have this same question both for deployment through a terminal (See Step 6 of above tutorial) and for deployment through an IDE (e.g. through Maven in Eclipse).

I imagine that somehow the terminal (or the IDE) gets your credentials from the browser, which is logged in to the GAE console but I am not sure at all this is the good explanation.

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to authenticate when deploying to Google App Engine. The recommended method uses [OAuth2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0%20OAuth2) to authenticate with Google (see below for another method). OAuth2 is the method used in the tutorial you mentioned (search for oauth in the link you sent), and is activated by the setting

```
appcfg {
  oauth2 = true
}
```

in the `build.gradle` file of that tutorial. If you prefer the command-line `appcfg` interface, use the flag `appcfg --oauth2`.

When you installed the Google Cloud SDK, you were shown a web page in which you authorized the SDK to access and modify various Google Cloud services, including App Engine. The SDK locally stores a token which indicates that it is allowed to deploy to App Engine under your username. The `oauth2 = true` line tells appcfg to request access to App Engine using this token.

If you like, you can view (and revoke) this authorization by navigating to Google's [Account Permissions](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) page. You should see an entry for Google Cloud SDK, and clicking on it will show you that the SDK is authorized to access App Engine. If you click on "Revoke", the locally stored token will no longer be valid and you will need to re-authorize in order to use most of the Cloud SDK functionality.

If for some reason you do not want to rely on oauth2 (for example, if for security reasons you want to enter a password every time you deploy), then you can remove the `oauth2 = true` line (or the `--oauth2` command-line argument). This will cause appcfg to prompt for your Google username and password each time you deploy. However, this is a lot less convenient, both because appcfg will not store your password, and because it does not support 2-factor authentication. So, if your Google account uses 2-factor authentication (which is really recommended), you will need to use an App Password with this approach.